# Using VBA to insert a sort formula

Tags: excel, vba

How do I insert a sort function with VBA, so the whole range gets sorted.

This is the function I want to insert:

```
=SORT(A2:B" & LastRowB & ",2,-1,FALSE)
```

What i get is

```
=@SORT(A2:B3662;2;-1;FALSE)
```

This one is without the needed spill function

Comment: Use .formula2..

Comment: Thank you Scott!

Answer (score 3):

For reasons of backwards compatibility, the default behaviour for things like `Range("A1").Formula` is the non-array, single result function. This is by design and prevents formulas that have been created before Dynamic Arrays existed, so existing VBA solutions won't all of a sudden calculate those functions that are now array aware as arrays.

If you want to get the array version instead of the single version of the formula, you can use

`Range("A1").Formula2 = Sort(.....)`